# setPeerCount doctrine equivalent

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

In propel setPeerCountMethod is used to change the count query in pagination. Does anybody know its equivalent in doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nm I think I found it:

$pager->setCountQuery($query [, $params = null])

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/utilities:pagination